# How to Invoke a windows service from SQL query

Tags: sql, windows, service

I want to know if their any way to invoke a windows service from SQL query ? 
note that : the windows service is installed on the same SQL server

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because windows services cannot be invoked. A service is just a process that is started by the SCM and responds to the [SCM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) commands, there is no such concept as 'invoking' a service. What you can interact with is the service API, which implies a communication protocol with the service. Depending on the API and protocol used, that may be possible to do from T-SQL. Eg. COM based APIs can be interacted using [`sp_OAcreate`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190501.aspx), managed APIs may be interacted using [SQLCLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) and so on. But is always a Bad Idea. T-SQL is not the proper layer to introduce dependencies on external services, it may impact the SQL performance dramatically and, most importantly, is almost always incorrect due to not proerly considering rollbacks.

Do any/all service interaction in the application layer, where it belongs.